# VisualOcaml wanted to write a deminer (rather than using Ocaml's graphics library)

Tags: graphics, ocaml

In Ocaml, is there  easier ways to write a graphics-based toy programs like deminer (like the one that comes with Windows 95)? I find the only way is to start by scratch using Ocaml's graphics library. There must be better ways around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are bindings to the SDL library, that provides more features than Graphics.
There are actually several of them, and I'm not exactly sure which is best:

- [SdlCaml](http://glcaml.sourceforge.net/) is a part of the [GLcaml] project
- the [OcamlSDL](http://ocamlsdl.sourceforge.net/home.html) library

I think SdlCaml is more bare metal (probably partly automatically generated), and OCamlSDL is an older (but still occasionally updated) library with a larger user base.

Note however that Graphics is simple to use for a start, and you can still move to something more sophisticated later. If you run into speed-of-rendering issues, you have to use double buffering, as explained [in the manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Graphics.html#6_Doublebuffering).